# How to use the GAE blobstore with a user table? (EntityNotFoundError)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've just started using the GAE Blobstore to upload image files to a web app. I've been using these resources as tutorials:

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/03/Implementing-a-dropbox-service-with-the-Blobstore-API-Part-1
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

In my code below a blob will upload to the datastore ok and I can also retrieve the blob information ok. However after a variable delay (maybe 5min+) I start to get EntityNotFoundErrors when trying to read the blob information. The blob and UserFile data still appear in the _ah/admin/datastore interface.

As I'm new to developing with the blobstore I was wondering if my use of blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty is ok?

Thanks in advance for any advice,

Brian

I use the following data structure to link user records to blobs:

```
class UserFile(db.Model):
  user = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  blob_key = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty(required=True)
```

I write blobs to the DB like this (The username is retrieved through self.get_username):

```
def write_blob(self, data, info):
        blob = files.blobstore.create(
            mime_type=info['type'],
            _blobinfo_uploaded_filename=info['name']
        )
        with files.open(blob, 'a') as f:
            f.write(data)
        files.finalize(blob)

        # Add a userfile entry for this blob
        key =  files.blobstore.get_blob_key(blob)
        userFile = UserFile(blob_key = key, user = self.get_username()) 
        userFile.put()
```

Finally, I retrieve the blob information like this:

```
 def get_userFileTable(self):
    username = self.get_username()
    userfiles = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                            "FROM UserFile "
                            "WHERE user = :1",username)

    for userfile in userfiles:
        filename = userfile.blob_key.filename
```

The final line is where the EntityNotFoundError is thrown

```
File "\scripts\filemanager\upload_handler.py", line 188, in get_userFileTable filename = userfile.blob_key.filename
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\blobstore\blobstore.py", line 179, in filename return self.__get_value('filename')
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\blobstore\blobstore.py", line 243, in __get_value
self.kind(), str(self.__key), namespace=''))
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 628, in Get
return GetAsync(keys, **kwargs).get_result()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 592, in get_result
return self.__get_result_hook(self)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_rpc.py", line 1467, in __get_hook
entities = rpc.user_data(entities)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 597, in local_extra_hook
raise datastore_errors.EntityNotFoundError()
EntityNotFoundError
```

I am using app engine development server 1.6.5 on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look in the SDK admin console : do you see your entity?
Or do you clear the entities on every SDK start with the --clear flag?

Comment: Thanks for the reply voscausa, Yes I can see the entity and the user entry in the admin console. I've also tried the getUserFileTable code in the admin console terminal and have the same result. I don't close the AppEngineLauncher between tests and also get the number of results I expect from GQLQuery, just the blob_key.filename reference gives EntityNotFoundError

Comment: I do not see an error, maybe the user object changes?? Did you try to deploy it, maybe it is a SDK problem.

Comment: Hi voscausa, thanks for checking the code was correct. I found out what was wrong -- me being silly! The jquery demo code I used had a function to remove all blob entries after a set amount of time to avoid filling up the blobstore. I assumed it was how I was using the blobstore that was wrong and didn't check the demo code properly (to much of a hurry). Your validation of my code helped me realise it was something else so I marked your answer correct. Thanks again.